# Can I travel to Jamaica with a one way ticket and buy a return once I am there?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets, us-citizens, proof-of-onward-travel, jamaica

I would like to know if I can buy a return ticket once I am there as I do not know how long I will be staying. I will be staying with relatives if that makes a difference.

OR could I buy a ticket and within 24hrs cancel once I make it through customs?

Comment: I am an American

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=JM&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) advises:

> Immigration authorities may request visitors and transit passengers to prove that they will depart from the country within the prescribed period, by showing a return or onward ticket to their next international destination.
>
> Unless stated otherwise, return/onward ticket is defined as:
>
> a. International airline ticket (i.e. any types of airline tickets, reservation confirmation, booking code etc.); or
>
> b. Evidence of departing from the country by other means of transportation (e.g. confirmation of joining a cruise, train, bus or ferry tickets, proof of departing by private boat or plane, etc).

The chances of you being asked to show a return ticket on arrival are probably very low however.

... though first you have to be allowed to board.

Comment: This is not the info relevant for Jamaica

Comment: What shows when cklicking "For details, click here" is general info about the concept of requiring return/onward tickets, not country-specific info. The shorter version in the Jamaica info page is Jamaica-specific

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=JM&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) the database used by airlines:

> Visitors **must** hold return/onward tickets

It doesn't say "**must**" for most countries, but here it does.

Basically, if the check-in staff checks you carefully enough and notices this, you're **not** getting on your flight without a return/onward ticket.

If you do make it do Jamaican immigration, it's unlikely that they'll care.

So **yes**, buy a flexible ticket and cancel it once in Jamaica